# Simple example: Property or method "sayHello" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I'm following a vue course on udemy.
It's a super simple example, but I get the error `Property or method "sayHello" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`.

I have an easy setup in vscode with two files: `index.html` and `script.js`, I run `index.html` in the browser

index.html

```
<div id="app">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    <p>{{sayHello()}}</p>
</div>



<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\[my name]\dev\Vue JS 2 - The Complete Guide (incl. Vue Router & Vuex\section01\script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        title: 'Hello World!'
    },
    methods: {
        sayHello: function () {
            return 'Hello Methods!';
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works. https://plnkr.co/edit/qTeQ2O4Hahtspu6Y?preview . Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. Notice that an app that is served from filesystem without webserver may not work as intended (doesn't seem to be your case but it will when features that are sensitive to this like routing are in use).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div id="app">
<p>{{this.title}}</p>
<p>{{this.sayHello()}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This just doesn't make any difference

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?